# pt-online-schema-change and replicas, how to proceed?

Tags: mysql, replication, database-schema, percona

I am using `pt-online-schema-change` to change my table schema without downtime, but how should I deal with replicas? As I understand, I need to run command on slave dbs as well?

Answer (score 0):

No, `pt-online-schema-change` will take care of all slaves as well. Also it will monitor that slave doesn't lag all too much.

If you are planning to do it on huge tables, to take caution and try it in low-traffic hours. We have seen PTOSC crash on multiple occasions, MySQL was crashing as well while dropping old table, etc, etc. It's a very handy tool, but needs to be carefully tested in your particular environment.